# Use PUT or PATCH verb when request is updating and deleting: Real life design

Tags: http, patch, put, http-verbs

I've been trying to get the HTTP verbs right lately, however I have a doubt regarding using PUT, PATCH or even POST for the following scenario.

The front end part is sending the following JSON data:

```
{
    name: "Spanish-01",
    code: "ESP01",
    students: [{
        IdStudent: 1,
        name:  "Peter Parker"
    },
    {
        IdStudent: 2
        name:  "Ben Reilly",
        dirtyRemove: true
    }]
}
```

The back end code will update the **Class** record (e.g name and code). However, it will also delete the students with flag dirtyRemove,  and those live in another table called **Student**.

So what's the rule here? Since PUT and PATCH according to [w3.org here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6) is for updating an existing resource. In this case the back end is both updating and deleting at the same time?

**Should I use PUT or PATCH or neither?**

**NOTE:** Don't mind about the FE part, I minimized the scope in order to get a more straightforward example

Answer (score 1):

How your resources are implemented internally using tables is an implementation detail. It doesn't matter.

That said, your example payload doesn't fit PUT (to remove a student, you would omit it). It *might* fit PATCH, if you properly label the payload with a content type describing what semantics you expect.

Nit: the HTTP spec is not a W3 document, and the version you're looking at is outdated.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the  current-latest doc?